# How do I continuously run in python virtual environment on google cloud engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to run a cron job that executes a python script on google compute engine in a virtual environment. When I exit the shell I am ssh'd into the virtual environment goes away however. How do I persistently run in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your task as a Startup Script or use Cloud Scheduler to do the job.

1. Documentation to see [how to run startup scripts on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).
2. Documentation on [how to implement Event scheduling on Compute Engine Virtual Machine used distributed messaging](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine). There is also [example code of this implementation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine-sample) on the GitHub